# Neovim startup: faster on the second run, how do I warm it up?

Tags: neovim, startup

I noticed that the second time I run `nvim` it loads much faster (on Windows 11).

Ideally, what I want is this something like `nvim --warmup-then-exit`, which I would run on session startup/login. How could I achieve this?

Why it faster? I don't see any spawned processes.

Environment: `nvim 0.9.0 on Windows 11`

**Aside:** I also noticed that the identical version+config in linux is substantially faster --- but that is a topic for another day.

Comment: Do you run it on Windows?

Comment: May be antivirus?

Comment: "May be antivirus?", good idea - I will investigate